# raphael animate shape

Tags: javascript, raphael

I don't want a whole chart library for this. All I want is to animate 1 rectangular box from 0 to a set value, like a linear guage, but without the need for labels or array of values. Whats the cleanest way to do this, using raphael. The guage container should have background color set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
square.animate({height: scale}, 1000, 'bounce');
```